# Sort strings that contains letters and numbers in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am pulling through variations(options) of a product. Each variation/option has a different name/code and sometimes it contains a mixture of numbers and letters.

I would like to know if there is a way I can sort this in a neat way.

Please see picture attach of how the variations are currently listed.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [sort](http://php.net/sort)?

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want them to be sorted? These look quite right to me

Comment: Show us your php code, from where they comes ?

Comment: This question makes little sense, if you do not state what a “neat way” of sorting these would be by your definition.

Comment: it needs SORT_NATURAL, SORT_FLAG_CASE in sort function

Comment: Proof that the dupe target works: https://3v4l.org/ZrK8C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) can do that for you. Here's an example from the PHP page doing pretty much the same thing you are trying to do:

```
$fruits = array(
    "Orange1", "orange2", "Orange3", "orange20"
);

sort($fruits, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

This example will output:

```
fruits[0] = Orange1
fruits[1] = orange2
fruits[2] = Orange3
fruits[3] = orange20
```